# Tosca : Unable to identify SAP web UI element due to unmapped controls

Tags: tosca

I am facing a problem while scanning a SAP web UI application. Upon scanning I am receiving "there are unmapped controls".
Can someone tell me what is mapped and unmapped controls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hemant,

I know *unmapped controls* just in the context of re-scanning. Re-scanning basically means, that you already have a module in Tosca, created earlier by you or one of your colleagues. And now you are trying to *synchronize* it with the application. It can't find *all* the controls already available in the module - those it couldn't find are marked as "unmapped". This can have several reasons:

1) you ran re-scan by accident and what you really want to do is scan
(re-scan is to update an existing module, scan is to create a new one)

2) controls have been removed from the page (then you can't map them)

3) controls have been modified (then you can map the unmapped controls to the according controls).

Sounds confusing...? [Here is more on the topic](https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.3.0&url=tchb/synchronizing_xmodules.htm).

Still confused...? [Please reach out to Tricentis' support](https://support.tricentis.com/community/contact.do).

Michael